# What are the set of vectors that satisfies this quadratic form equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be any $N\times N$ hermitian matrix. What are the set of of all vectors which satisfy 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}==c
\end{align}
for some given constant $c$. More specifically, let $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{bb}^H$, can we be more specific to the solution of the previous question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\alpha b + y$, where $y \bot b$. Then $x^*bb^*x = |\alpha|^2 \|b\|^4$. Hence if $c \ge 0$, then all solutions of $x^*bb^*x =c$ are given by $e^{i\theta}{\sqrt{c} \over \|b\|^2}b + y $, where $y \bot b$ and $\theta$ is arbitrary. If $c <0$, there are no solutions.