# What are the set of vectors satisfying this quadratic form equality (real entries only)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

This question was [already asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670594/what-are-the-set-of-vectors-that-satisfies-this-quadratic-form-equality) in the case of Hermitian matrices, which have complex entries.

I want to pose the same question in the case of matrices which have only real entries. I.e. for a given $c$ How to determine the set of vectors $\mathbf{x}$ satisfying the quadratic form equality

$$\mathbf{x^TMx}=c$$

where $\mathbf{M}$ is a non-singular (square, p.d., probably symmetric) matrix with only real entries.

Forgive me if I should have been able to figure this out from the linked post.

Comment: By definition, the solution set is a quadric (hyper)surface. If $\bf M$ is symmetric, then Sylvester's Law of Inertia implies there is a matrix $P$ such that $P^T M P$ has the form $\textrm{diag}(1, \ldots, 1, -1, \ldots, -1)$, and so the corresponding change of basis puts the quadric into a standard form, for which parameterizations are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  x^T M x & = c \\
  x^T V \Lambda V^T x & = c && M \text{ is symmetric and real, so can use spectral theorem} \\
  y^T \Lambda v & = c && y = V^T x \\
  y^T \Lambda^{1/2} \Lambda^{1/2} y &= c && M \text{ is PSD so the square roots exist} \\
  ||\Lambda^{1/2} y||^2 &= c \\
  \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i^2 &= c \\
  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i^2}{\Big(\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}\Big)^2} &= 1 && \text{Equation of an axis-aligned ellipsoid with }i \text{-th axis length }  \frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} \\
\end{align*}

Once you have $y$, you can solve for $x$ as $Vy = x$. So, the isosurface is an ellipsoid transformed by $V$.

Notice also that the $i$-th axis vector $w^i$ is given by

\begin{align*}
  w_{j}^i & = \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} & i = j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

So, when transforming the axes by $V$ we find that the $i$-th axis vector $z^i$ is given by

\begin{align*}
  z^i & = Vw^i \\
 & = \frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} v_i && \text{where } v_i \text{ is the } i\text{-th eigenvector of } M 
\end{align*}

This is because $V$ is a matrix where the $i$-th column is the $i$-th eigenvector of $M$. Therefore, **the shape of the solution set to $x^TMx=c$ is an ellipsoid centered at the origin with the eigenvectors of $M$ as axes with lengths $\frac{\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}$**

I should note that I recognized this problem because it's basically the same as the problem found starting on page 42 of [the notes for my machine learning class](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/machlearn.pdf). That's page 42 in the actual text, page 48 in the pdf file.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Very helpful, although I don't quite get how you can just drop out $V$. When I work through an example it sort of seems okay, but this would mean you could replace $x^TMx$ with $x^T \Lambda x$ any time $M$ is symmetric. That seems like cheating.

Comment: @ben Whoops, you're right. I changed my answer.

Comment: @ben Check out my latest edit. I added some important details about what the shape is after transforming by $V$.